# how to find width extended of the submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please look at the image,
i have a menu at the left of window,
sometime the Submenu confused and go out of the window,
i'm want to find value of submenu that go out of window
,this is my html code:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a class="basket" href="#">مشتریان ما
        </a>
        <div class="submenu">
            نمونه زیر منو
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a class="employ" href="#">دعوت به همکاری
        </a>
        <div class="submenu">
            نمونه زیر منو
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a class="about-us" href="#">درباره ما
        </a>
        <div class="submenu">
            نمونه زیر منو
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a class="contact" href="#">تماس با ما
        </a>
        <div class="submenu">
            نمونه زیر منو
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and also my css here:

```
.submenu
{
    background: #fff;
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity ease-in 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-in 0.5s;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.nav li:hover > .submenu
{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity ease-in 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-in 0.5s;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to show some code

Comment: Looks like a positioning issue.

Comment: i'm add the css and html code on the post

Comment: It seems that the code you posted is incomplete... can you also create a JSFiddle that reproduces your problem?

Comment: here is:
http://jsfiddle.net/yspPb/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it could do the job for you, but you could try anyway.

You have to calculate your window width.
Then calculate your submenu width and offset left.
Now, you know if your submenu is out of your window, and how much your submenu is out.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var subOffsetLeft = $(this).offset().left;
var subWidth = $(this).width();

var rightOfSub = subOffsetLeft + subWidth;

if (rightOfSub > windowWidth) {
    var expendedSize = rightOfSub - windowWidth;
    alert(expendedSize)
}
```

You can see it working in this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yspPb/3/)**. Hope it help.

**EDIT #1 :**

If you want to adjust submenus to prevent them from going out of the window, you can modify margin depending on how much they are out  : **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yspPb/4/)**

Comment: your code is work and return extended value but not solve my problem,do you have any other idea to fix the issue?